# How can I create a running list of connected protocols that have searchable attributes with twisted?

Tags: python, tcp, server, twisted

I'm trying to create a server that accepts TCP connections that has a running list of current connections. My current factory and protocol is as follows:

```
class KConnectProtocol(Protocol):
...

    # Adds +1 to the client count whenever a new connection is made, while     
    # also putting a log entry for the client IP and time stamp.
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.client = self.transport.client
        log.msg('K connected from: ' + self.client[0])
        self.factory.numProtocols = self.factory.numProtocols + 1
        log.msg('There are ' + str(self.factory.numProtocols) + ' k connected.')

        self.factory.kList.append(self)
...

class KFactory(ServerFactory):

     # numProtocols keeps track of the number of clients connected to the server at
     # any given point. It's an attribute of the factory so it can be called globally
     protocol = KConnectProtocol
     numProtocols = 0
     kList = []
     uid = []
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is search **kList** based on the UID of each protocol. Ie;

```
k1.uid = 123
k2.uid = 234
k3.uid = 345

kList = (k1, k2, k3)
```

Now, each item in the list represents a unique TCP connection. I want to search kList for the attribute "234". Once I've identified the index of the object, I *should* be able to do a `k2.transport.write("Whoopee")` to send something over that specific TCP connection. However I'm running into a roadblock where I'm not sure where to declare that attribute, and if a list would even be searchable to that degree.

To cover everything my questions are as follows:

1. Where would I create the attribute (`uid`) so that each connection has a unique identifier, in the protocol init?
2. How could I make a list of objects (protocols) that are searchable on that attribute?

I'm fairly new to python and brand new to twisted and networking, any help or points in the right direction would be helpful! (As a side note, I've searched SO pretty extensively and found some answers, but nothing that seems to answer this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer for myself and I wanted to post it here.

In order to create a unique name for each of my protocol instances I created the attribute in the connectionMade method:

```
class KConnectProtocol(Protocol):

    # Adds +1 to the client count whenever a new connection is made, while
    # also putting a log entry for the client IP and time stamp.
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.client = self.transport.client
        log.msg('K connected from: ' + self.client[0])
        self.factory.numProtocols = self.factory.numProtocols + 1
        log.msg('There are ' + str(self.factory.numProtocols) + ' k connected.')

        self.factory.kList.append(self)

        self.kUID = ""
```

This adds it as an attribute to each instance (connection) that is made, so you can set your own identifier for each one.

```
    for x in self.factory.kList:
        if x.kUID == "12345":
            x.transport.write("It works!\n")
```

Here I'm able to identify a specific connection, and use that UID to send information to just that connection.

Doing `print x.__dict__` will actually print everything for that instance which is what led me to the answer. With the factory keeping track of the kList, this can be used to reference a connection anywhere in the particular factory scope.

I'm still working on making it more efficient, but hopefully this helps someone else as well!

Comment: You shouldn't use `self.transport.client`; that's an accidentally-exposed attribute, only present on some implementations.  ITransport defines `getPeer` - https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html#getPeer - which is what you want in this circumstance.  Also, you should treat it as an https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.address.IPv4Address.html and not a tuple, so use the `.host` attribute.  Otherwise: the right answer!